# Returning an RAII container class that holds a std::mutex lock

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'd like to wrap all usages of a class instance with a mutex. Today I have

```
std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<MyClass>> classes;
```

and functions to find and return instances, like:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> GetClass(int i);
```

I'd like to ensure that GetClass() can only retrieve an instance if someone else hasn't already retrieved it, with some RAII mechanism. Usage would be like:

```
void CallingFunction()
{
    auto c = GetClass(i); // mutex for class id 'i' is acquired here

    // some calls to class
    c.SomeFunction();
} // mutex is released here when 'c' goes out of scope
```

With the mutex acquired by CallingFunction() other threads that wanted to access the same class instance would block on their calls to GetClass().

I've been looking at a few ways of doing it, such as with a wrapper class like:

```
class ClassContainer
{
    public:
        std::shared_ptr<Class> c;
        std::mutex m;
};
```

Where I'd modify GetClass() to be:

```
ClassContainer GetClass(int i);
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out both where the std::mutex should be kept, I tried initially storing it in the map before moving to using a container class like:

```
std::map<int, std::pair<std::mutex, std::shared_ptr<MyClass<>>> classes;
```

but that wasn't working well, now with the ClassContainer how to have ClassContainer lock the std::mutex like std::lock_guard<> when the caller acquires one via a call to GetClass().

Comment: so return a `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` with your class

Comment: You need one mutex for the map, and one for each individual value it contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've been looking at a few ways of doing it, such as with a wrapper class like:

Yes this is proper way to do it and you are close, but you cannot keep `mutex` itself in this class, only locker. And [`std::unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unique_lock) is a proper type for that as it has necessary move ctor etc. I would make fields private though and create necessary accessors:

```
class ClassContainer
{
    std::shared_ptr<Class> c;
    std::uniqe_lock<mutex> lock;
public:
    ClassContainer( std::pair<std::mutex,std::shared_ptr<Class>> &p ) :
        c( p.second ),
        lock( p.first ) 
    {
    }
    Class * operator->()const { return c.get(); }
    Class & operator*() const { return *c; }
};
```

then usage is simple:

```
void CallingFunction()
{
    auto c = GetClass(i); // mutex for class id 'i' is acquired here

    // some calls to class
    c->SomeFunction();
    // or even
    GetClass(i)->SomeFunction();
}
```

Comment: would you have some idea where I would/could keep the mutex if there was one mutex per instance of the class? In the map? In a separate parallel map?

Comment: Your solution with `tsd::pair` as value in `std::map` would work, I actually created constructor of `ClassContainer` based on that. It should be in class itself or that map, parallel map would be error prone solution.

Comment: How does one insert a pair of std::mutex, std::shared_ptr<Class>? I'm doing something like classes.insert(std::make_pair(i, std::make_pair(std::mutex, classInstance))); and getting a ton of compile issues.

Comment: `map[newI].second = std::make_shared<Class>( ... );` should work, or use `std::move` and/or `std::map::emplace` - `std::mutex` is not copyable

Comment: If I'm returning ClassContainer from GetClass() any thoughts on how I might let the caller know the class with the given 'i' value isn't found? I could throw std::out_of_range but was looking for other ideas to consider all my options.

Comment: It depends what you want to happen on not found condition. If it is exceptional situation throw exception, if not assign `nullptr` to `std::shared_ptr` and add a method to `ClassContainer` for example `operator bool`

Answer (score 1):

It is `Class` which should hold the `mutex`, something like:

```
class Class
{
public:

    // Your methods...

    std::mutex& GetMutex() { return m; }
private:
    std::mutex m;
};

class ClassContainer
{
public:
    ClassContainer(std::shared_ptr<Class> c) :
         c(std::move(c)),
         l(this->c->GetMutex())
    {}

    ClassContainer(const ClassContainer&) = delete;
    ClassContainer(ClassContainer&&) = delete;
    ClassContainer& operator =(const ClassContainer&) = default;
    ClassContainer& operator =(ClassContainer&&) = default;

    // For transparent pointer like access to Class.
    decltype(auto) operator -> () const { return c; }
    decltype(auto) operator -> () { return c; }

    const Class& operator*() const { return *c; }
    Class& operator*() { return *c; }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Class> c;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l;
};

ClassContainer GetClass(int i)
{
    auto c = std::make_shared<Class>();
    return {c}; // syntax which avoids copy/move contructor.
}
```

and finally usage:

```
auto&& cc = GetClass(42); // `auto&&` or `const&` pre-C++17, simple auto possible in C++17

cc->ClassMethod();
```

[Simplified demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e908b6c286d9f63).

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally, I did something extremely similar recently (only I returned references to objects instead of `shared_ptr`. The code worked like following:

```
struct locked_queue {
    locked_queue(locked_queue&& ) = default;
    mutable std::unique_lock<decltype(queue::mutex)> lock;
    const queue::q_impl_t& queue; // std::deque
};
```

And here is how it would be used:

```
locked_queue ClassX::get_queue(...) {
    return {std::unique_lock<decltype(mutex)>{mutex}, queue_impl};
}
```